# How to solve "No Synchronization Info at this position" Issue?

Tags: todonotes

Recently, I found a very weird problem for reverse search (I used MikTeX on Windows 10, the PDF viewer is SumatraPDF): The reverse search only works at certain locations in the generated PDF, whereas for the other locations, you will get the "No synchronization info at this position" issue.

With lots of efforts, I found that the cause seems to be the `todonotes` package. An MWE (minimal working example) is presented at the end of this description. It seems that the `todonotes` package only "disable" the synchronization for content within the `input`ed files (Note that if commenting out `\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}`, reverse search works on both sections). That is the reverse search only works on the contents directly appeared in the `main.tex`, whereas it fails on those within the "input"ed files (i.e., the contents in the second section in the MWE).

Is there any solution to make the reverse search work on both cases? Or does anyone find other packages that have similar problems?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\title{No Synchronization Info: Example}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test}

Click content within this section, reverse search works.

\input{sections/sec01}

\end{document}
```

where `sections/sec01.tex` has the following content:

```
\section{Test}

However, click content within this section, you will get ``No synchronization info at this position'' error.
```

Comment: The problem is tikz and the fadings library, if fails too  if I replace todonotes by `\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}`. Add an issue at the synctex bug tracker: https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex.

Comment: Seems like there is a bug report now: https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex/issues/32